# Grails Groovy MVC : Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0];

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I am running a job at a 5 second interval, it seems persistence is overlapping. I am getting the following error:

`Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1`

Any guidance on how to remedy this would be most appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the same job from firing while currently executing add the following to your job class:

```
def concurrent = false
```